# Split and Maintain Delimiter

Tags: ruby, regex, split

> September 1997, such and such

I need to split the above text into

```
September 1997
such and such
```

The delimiter is 1997, that is

> /[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\,/

How can I do it in ruby via regex?

That's my attempt:

> "September 1997, such and
>   such".to_s.split(/\s+(?=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\,)/)

Output:

```
September
1997, such and such
```

What I want is:

```
September 1997
such and such
```

Comment: I'm not sure to get the wanted output... Could you explain it clearly? To me you just wrote `September 1997 such and such` twice :/

Comment: Please provide more clarity on your case. Are you always wanting to split each line exactly once, right before a year and a comma? Does it matter what else is around it? As a side note, calling to_s isn't necessary when you already have a string.

Comment: `September 1997 such and such` What happend to the comma, why did it magically dissapear?

Comment: Ops! I fixed. I forgot to add the breakline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting `September 1997, such and such` like this

`(?<=\d{4}),\s*`

should get this output

```
September 1997
such and such
```

You could even add extra whitespace

`(?<=\d{4})\s*,\s*`

for variability and trimming.

Answer (score 0):

Note this only splits once, but that seems to be what you want?

```
str = "September 1997, such and such"
p str.match(/(.*?)([0-9]{4}.*)/)
# => #<MatchData "September 1997, such and such" 1:"September " 2:"1997, such and such">
```

This does do multiple splits (edited to include `\b` thanks to p11y)

```
p str.split(/(?=\b\d{4}\b)/)
# => ["September ", "1997, such and such"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using positive lookahead, you can split at the empty string, followed by a decimal (`\d`). In this case that means that the empty string must be followed by a decimal, but the decimal will not be part of the split.

```
"September 1997, such and such".split(/(?=\d)/)
#=> ["September ", "1997, such and such"]
```

If you need to match exactly four decimals you can use a quantifier (`{n}`), e.g.

```
"September 1997, such and such".split(/(?=\d{4})/)
#=> ["September ", "1997, such and such"]
```

If you want to get rid of the space in between, you can additionally capture one or more whitespace characters (`\s+`) instead of the empty string:

```
"September 1997, such and such".split(/\s+(?=\d)/)
#=> ["September", "1997, such and such"]
```